# Python Dataframe Issue?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create data frame of Share prices based on data provided by vendor. I am getting an error message "'Series' object has no attribute 'close'" Can you please help me with this issue ?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import quandl
import datetime as dt
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'Hba3CzgNnEa2LMxR14FA'

stock_list = pd.read_csv(r"F:\Abhay_New\Abhay\Python\Project\SHARADAR_SF1.csv")
end_date = dt.date.today()
diff_year = dt.timedelta(days=365)
start_date = end_date - diff_year
path = (r"F:\Tradepoint\MyMkt")

for i in range(len(stock_list)):
    data = quandl.get_table('SHARADAR/SEP', date={'gte':start_date, 'lte':end_date}, ticker=stock_list.iloc[i])
    if len(data)>1:
        dict = {'Date':data['date'],'OPEN':data['open'],'HIGH':data['high'],'LOW':data['low'],'CLOSE':data['close'],'VOLUME':data['volume']}
        final_data = pd.DataFrame(dict,columns = ['Date','OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME'])
        final_data.to_csv(path + '\\' + stock_list.iloc[i] + '.csv', index = False, header = False)
        print(final_data).head()


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback, it's not clear what line that's happening on.

Comment: Hi Add. Can you please also provide the output of `print(data)` after you declare the variable

Comment: Date    OPEN    HIGH     LOW   CLOSE      VOLUME
                                                                 
0     2018-12-24 00:00:00  158.53  159.36  156.48  157.74  35003466.0
1     2018-12-24 00:00:00  157.50  158.52  154.55  156.23  40808185.0
2     2018-12-24 00:00:00  155.84  156.77  150.07  156.15  50433451.0
3     2018-12-24 00:00:00  148.30  157.23  146.72  157.17  57438006.0
4     2018-12-24 00:00:00  148.15  151.55  146.59  146.83  37155354.0

Comment: This is likely happening on the "dict = {'Date':data..." line.  It's telling you the data doesn't have a "close" field.  You should print out data as recommended by previous user and make sure the structure matches your assumptions regarding presence/absence of field names.  Also, dict is a reserved word in Python - declaring a local variable over it is not a good idea (better to call it my_dict or some such).

Comment: In your `print(data)`, the column names  (except `Date`) are all capitalized, e.g. `CLOSE`, but when you define the `dict`, you used `'CLOSE':data['close']`. This might cause the issue.

Comment: @PeptideWitch Please see the below output of print(data) and let me know your view.

Comment: @NeilZ is right. Looks like you're accessing the dictionary with the wrong keys. You need to be consistent with your strings: 'CLOSE' != 'close'

Comment: @PeptideWitch I have tried all possible combination but it's still giving me an error message. I dont understand why it has problem with "close" and not any other variable.